# Disable Firefox Dialogue box On page leave by using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser

How I can disable the Firefox Dialogue Box on page leave by using JavaScript or Jquery?

I tried multiple event  **window.onbeforeunload** but not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress these warnings by setting

```
window.onbeforeunload = null
```

I just tried it on this stackoverflow page and it works.

Comment: Can you share the link where you tried this line?

Comment: @XeeShan I tried it on this post. I tried it using the developer console. I am using the latest version of Firefox.